# When resolving a symlink with boost the result doesn't equal the original path name

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Windows 10
MS VS 2015
C++11
Boost 1.60

I create this symbolic link:

`mklink /J "C:\T4 2.0\ApplicationSymlinks\T4"  "C:\T4 2.0\Data"`

This is a much simplified version of a program to check if the symbolic link is linked to the proper directory:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    boost::filesystem::path directory = "c:\\T4 2.0\\Data";

    boost::filesystem::path symlink = "c:\\T4 2.0\\ApplicationSymlinks\\T4";
    boost::filesystem::path path_linked_to("");
    path_linked_to = boost::filesystem::read_symlink(symlink);    // Resolve symlink. path_linked_to is not absolute. L"\\T4 2.0\\Data"
    path_linked_to = boost::filesystem::absolute(path_linked_to); // Absolute path. L"c:\\T4 2.0\\Data"

    if (directory == path_linked_to)
        std::cout << "paths are equal" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "paths are not equal" << std::endl;                    
    return 0;
}
```

The output is "paths are not equal". Shouldn't they be equal? In the autos window of the debugger I do see this:

```
directory size 14 capacity 15
```

where as

```
path_linked_to size 16 capacity 23 because it includes two trailing '\0's.
```

These two trailing `'\0'`s are introduced in `read_symlink`.

How do I resolve this? Why doesn't `read_symlink` return an absolute? Why does `read_symlink` add in two trailing `'\0'`s (assuming that is the problem)? Why does `operator==` not ignore the `'\0'`s?

How I compiled and linked:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe /c /IC:\Libraries\boost_1_60_0 /ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /sdl /Od /D _DEBUG /D _CONSOLE /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"x64\Debug\\" /Fd"x64\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:prompt resolvesymlilnk.cpp stdafx.cpp

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /OUT:"c:\Users\Therefore\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\resolvesymlilnk\x64\Debug\resolvesymlilnk.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Libraries\boost_1_60_0\lib64-msvc-14.0" kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /Debug /PDB:"c:\Users\Therefore\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\resolvesymlilnk\x64\Debug\resolvesymlilnk.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"c:\Users\Therefore\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\resolvesymlilnk\x64\Debug\resolvesymlilnk.lib" /MACHINE:X64 x64\Debug\resolvesymlilnk.obj
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in Boost: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10900

Unfortunately it hasn't been fixed yet and has been assigned a low priority, so if you want it fixed you're going to have to do it yourself.

The problem is that when boost.filesystem reads the [`REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552012.aspx) structure, it assumes that the reparse is a symbolic link so always uses the `SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer` union member; for a junction it should use `MountPointReparseBuffer`. This means that the buffer calculations are `sizeof(ULONG)` off and so the read path is missing the drive letter and colon (`L"C:"`) and has two wide characters added at the end instead, which as you've observed are usually null characters. (The wide characters get converted to narrow characters on the way out of the boost.filesystem internals.)

The fix would be in [`read_symlink`](https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/blob/develop/src/operations.cpp#L1525) to check whether the `ReparseTag` member is `IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK` or `IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT` (as in [`is_reparse_point_a_symlink`](https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/blob/develop/src/operations.cpp#L586)), and use `SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer` or `MountPointReparseBuffer` respectively. As the ticket linked above says, Boost should really use `SubstituteNameOffset`/`SubstituteNameLength` instead of `PrintNameOffset`/`PrintNameLength` and strip the leading `L"\??\"` for absolute symlinks and for junctions.